# robots.txt configuration

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have a few doubts about this robots file.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /css/
Disallow: /func/
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /inc/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /login/
Disallow: /recover/
Disallow: /Scripts/
Disallow: /store/com-handler/
Disallow: /store/img/
Disallow: /store/theme/
Disallow: /store/StoreSys.swf
Disallow: config.php
```

This is going to disable crawlers for all files inside each folder right?
Or i have to add a asterisk at the end of each folder name?

I think this should do it. But i'm not sure if have to add `Allow: /` right after `User-agent` i suppose it isn't needed.

Anything wrong in this robots file?

PS: If someone can suggest a validation app for local use, i would be glad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine as is, if I understand what you want.  E.g.

```
/administrator/
/css/subpage
```

are both blocked, but

```
/foo
```

is allowed.  Note that Allow is a less supported extension designed only to counter a previous Disallow.  You might use it if, for instance, despite your

```
Disallow: /images/
```

you decide you want a particular image allowed.  So,

```
Allow: /images/ok_image
```

All other images remain blocked.  You can see http://www.searchtools.com/robots/robots-txt.html for more info, including a list of checkers.

Comment: Yes i think you have. I want all crawlers to index the website, with the exception of all those folders and files inside them. And that last php file.

Comment: Thanks for this last minute edit. It proved useful in another doubt i has having right now. And sure did cleared my mind of any doubts about the Allow condition. Thanks :D